# .htaccess Product page with slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What i'm trying to do is format my product urls like:

```
site.com/id-product-name/
```

Using my .htaccess i have this so far:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)-[^/]+\.html$ /service.php?serviceId=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This appends ".html" to the end of every product, which works great, but i would prefer a trailing slash at the end like shown above i tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)-[^/]+\/$ /service.php?serviceId=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But this doesn't work, i'm probably missing something small, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What url are you typing into your browser address bar and what error do you get?

Comment: URL rewriting processes *incoming* requests, translating them to point to actual resources. If you want URLs with a slash, they have to be like that on the *outgoing* response.